Comfy Ui + Web Socket
I have a Comfy Ui server running on a server, I wanted to use the api with web socket from my computer, but although there is no problem when the web socket is running on the local host, I get errors when I try with the server address. I used ngrok and cloudflared to redirect the server address, but neither of them worked. I need help
#This is an example that uses the websockets api to know when a prompt execution is done
#Once the prompt execution is done it downloads the images using the /history endpoint

import websocket #NOTE: websocket-client (https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client)
import uuid
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import requests
server_address = "badf-95-7-52-49.ngrok-free.app"
client_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

def queue_prompt(prompt):
    p = {"prompt": prompt, "client_id": client_id}
    data = json.dumps(p).encode('utf-8')
    req =  urllib.request.Request("http://{}/prompt".format(server_address), data=data)
    return json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read())

def get_image(filename, subfolder, folder_type):
    data = {"filename": filename, "subfolder": subfolder, "type": folder_type}
    url_values = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://{}/view?{}".format(server_address, url_values)) as response:
        return response.read()
    
# def set_image

def get_history(prompt_id):
    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://{}/history/{}".format(server_address, prompt_id)) as response:
        return json.loads(response.read())

def get_images(ws, prompt):
    prompt_id = queue_prompt(prompt)['prompt_id']
    output_images = {}
    while True:
        out = ws.recv()
        if isinstance(out, str):
            message = json.loads(out)
            if message['type'] == 'executing':
                data = message['data']
                if data['node'] is None and data['prompt_id'] == prompt_id:
                    break #Execution is done
        else:
            continue #previews are binary data

    history = get_history(prompt_id)[prompt_id]
    for o in history['outputs']:
        for node_id in history['outputs']:
            node_output = history['outputs'][node_id]
            if 'images' in node_output:
                images_output = []
                for image in node_output['images']:
                    image_data = get_image(image['filename'], image['subfolder'], image['type'])
                    images_output.append(image_data)
            output_images[node_id] = images_output

    return output_images


def upload_file(file, subfolder="", overwrite=False):
    try:
        # Wrap file in formdata so it includes filename
        body = {"image": file}
        data = {}
        
        if overwrite:
            data["overwrite"] = "true"
  
        if subfolder:
            data["subfolder"] = subfolder

        resp = requests.post(f"http://{server_address}/upload/image", files=body,data=data)
        
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            data = resp.json()
            # Add the file to the dropdown list and update the widget value
            path = data["name"]
            if "subfolder" in data:
                if data["subfolder"] != "":
                    path = data["subfolder"] + "/" + path
            

        else:
            print(f"{resp.status_code} - {resp.reason}")
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
    return path


#load workflow from file
with open("workflow3.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    workflow_data = f.read()

workflow = json.loads(workflow_data)

#set the text prompt for our positive CLIPTextEncode


#random seed
import random

seed = random.randint(1, 1000000000)

#set the image url
workflow["7"]["inputs"]["url"] = "https://i.hizliresim.com/6fy279d.jpg"
workflow["8"]["inputs"]["url"] = "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/D4D03AQGev1Jwi8TzCQ/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1713355416560?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=iiz8OYnb-lKz2pmpT0STkvTR3yShXWscYAW-6nJ1nXU"


ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("wss://requirements-mississippi-event-meeting.trycloudflare.com/".format(server_address, client_id))
images = get_images(ws, workflow)

#Commented out code to display the output images:

for node_id in images:
    for image_data in images[node_id]:
        from PIL import Image
        import io
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
        #image.show()
        # save image
        image.save(f"{node_id}-{seed}.png")

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\musta\OneDrive\Masaüstü\API\dreaminAI_websockets_api_example.py", line 126, in <module>
    ws.connect("wss://requirements-mississippi-event-meeting.trycloudflare.com/".format(server_address, client_id))
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 261, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, url, *addrs, **options)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 65, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\musta\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 150, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200 OK -+-+- {'date': 'Tue, 07 May 2024 19:33:36 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'cf-ray': '8803a4855b60b3a7-MUC', 'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'last-modified': 'Sun, 14 Apr 2024 16:12:18 GMT', 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true', 'access-control-allow-headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS', 'server': 'cloudflare'} -+-+- None

